# python argparse -- customizing error messages

Tags: python, error-handling, argparse

I want to generate custom error messages for particular usage errors in my command-line program that uses the `argparse` library.  I know I can override the general presentation of the error by subclassing `argparse.ArgumentParser`:

```
class HelpParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        sys.stderr.write('error: %s\n' % message)
        sys.exit(2)

parser = HelpParser(... ...)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

But when my `error` method is called, `message` has already been formatted by the library.  For example,

```
> python prog.py old stuff

usage: prog [-h] {hot,cold,rain,snow} ...
prog: error: argument subparser: invalid choice: 'old' (choose from u'hot', u'cold', u'rain', u'snow')
```

How can I change how the stuff after `error:` is presented, for instance to

```
usage: prog [-h] {hot,cold,rain,snow} ...
error: 'old' is not a valid option. select from 'hot', 'cold', 'rain', 'snow'
```

?

Comment: I revised your presentation of the question because, as far as I can tell, it doesn't have anything to do with *exceptions* (the language facility).  If I have misunderstood what you meant to ask, please let me know.

Comment: Which python version are you using and which os? I tried in Python 3.4 in windows, and I am not getting the issue you said

Comment: @zwol question reads much better. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.2/Lib/argparse.py#L2540), you could over-ride `this particular` error message by overriding this method:

```
def _check_value(self, action, value):
    # converted value must be one of the choices (if specified)
    if action.choices is not None and value not in action.choices:
        args = {'value': value,
                'choices': ', '.join(map(repr, action.choices))}
        msg = _('invalid choice: %(value)r (choose from %(choices)s)')
        raise ArgumentError(action, msg % args)
```

The issue is that if you wanted to override all possible error messages, you'd have to basically re-write this module.  All the various error messages are pre-formatted throughout -in the various methods that detect each type of error.

Comment: After posting the question, I began to realize that there probably wasn't a general solution. Like you say, you'd have to re-write the module to deliver custom error .messages which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @HenryThornton There should be a PEP for custom error potential. There isn't right now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Gerrat's answer, the `_` function is imported as

```
from gettext import gettext as _, ngettext
```

It is using the `gettext` module, https://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html, to enable internationalization.   I'm not familiar with that module, but presumably you could use it to perform a certain amount English paraphrasing.  But maybe not as much as you'd like.

Error messages pass through several levels.  Functions like `_check_values` write the basic message.  `ArgumentError` adds the argument name (`argument subparser:` in your example).  `parser.error` adds the `usage` and `prog`.  `parser.exit` takes care of the `sys.exit` step.

```
def error(self, message):
    ...
    self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
    args = {'prog': self.prog, 'message': message}
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
```