# I need to validate arguments from the command line

Tags: python

I need to make sure that when I run this from the command line and not enter any arguments a message is displayed(see last print statement) but what I am getting instead is:

```
C:\> python submitted.py (no arguments here)
usage: submitted.py [-h] user_string
submitted.py: error: the following arguments are required: user_string
```

How can I make this work?
here's the code:

```
import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('user_string', help='User string')
args = argparser.parse_args()
user_string = 0

# loop to check all conditions
if args.user_string:
    user_string = args.user_string
    # this will put the inputed words into a list
    words_to_sort = user_string.split()
    # Checking the number of inputs by user to meet criteria
    if len(words_to_sort) < 2:
        # alerts user to input more than 1 word
        print("Invalid command line arguments to program. Please, supply two or more strings to sort.")
    else:
        # sorts the list alphabetically
        words_to_sort.sort()
        # looping thru the list to display them
        for word in words_to_sort:
            # displaying the list
            print(word)
else:
    # if criteria not met user gets another message
    if (user_string < 1):
        print("Please input your words to be sorted")
```

Comment: But you do get an error message displayed. `ArgumentParser` does that for you, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: is there any way to change that error? That is what my assignment is.

Comment: Relevant but probably not the solution you want: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30956688/1247781

Comment: Alternatively you can wrap your code in a `try except` and then just rethrow your own custom exception. But this is overkill. Re-read your assignment to make sure that's really what it's asking you, because normally you don't want to re-code existing functionality. `argparse` allows you to have mandatory and optional arguments for this exact reason.

Comment: If you don't want `ArgumentParser` to handle the missing argument, you can make the argument optional and then handle the error yourself. See `ArgumentParser ` documentation for that. If that is your assignment, fine, but otherwise, it is a bad idea - letting `ArgumentParser` handle it is better.

Comment: what the assignment say is :
type:
python mySorter.py spencer able delta
see:
 able delta spencer
type:
python mySorter.py
see:
Invalid command line arguments to program. Please, supply two or
more strings to sort.